# Cmake not working. C compiler failing

Tags: macos, cmake

I'm trying to install a library on osx 10.11 but when I use cmake, it prints the output below. This has worked in the past (as in it worked yesterday), but something seems to have gone wrong since then. I've looked for an answer but can't seem to find anything that works. My Xcode and Xcode command line tools are all up to date. My cmake is up to date. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it to no avail. I've tested the c compiler and it's working as it should as far as I can tell. My openssl is also up to date, I tried reinstalling that as well without success. My Clang version is 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72). It's probably something obvious that I'm missing. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
$ pwd
<*current directory*>
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..

-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 7.0.0.7000072
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 7.0.0.7000072
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.2/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler
  "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang"
  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: <*current directory*>/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_e9215/fast"

  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9215.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9215.dir/build

  Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9215.dir/testCCompiler.c.o


  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
  -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9215.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c

  <*current directory*>/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c


  Linking C executable cmTC_e9215

  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9215.dir/link.txt --verbose=1


  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
  -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9215.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o
  cmTC_e9215

  ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib' for
  architecture x86_64

  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
  invocation)

  make[1]: *** [cmTC_e9215] Error 1

  make: *** [cmTC_e9215/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "<*current directory*>/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "<*current directory*>/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

This is the output of <*current directory*>/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log:

```
The system is: Darwin - 15.0.0 - x86_64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.out"

The C compiler identification is AppleClang, found in "<*current directory*>/build/CMakeFiles/3.3.2/CompilerIdC/a.out"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.out"

The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang, found in "<*current directory*>/build/CMakeFiles/3.3.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"
```

And this is the output of <*current directory*>/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log:

```
Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: <*current directory*>/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_e9215/fast"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9215.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9215.dir/build
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9215.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9215.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c <*current directory*>/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
Linking C executable cmTC_e9215
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9215.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang    -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib  CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9215.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_e9215
ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [cmTC_e9215] Error 1
make: *** [cmTC_e9215/fast] Error 2
```

**EDIT:**
Simple restart seemed to fix it. The obvious answer that I should have tried first. Sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the obvious solution. Off and on again. There's now a different error but one I think I can fix. Sorry for wasting everyone's time

Answer (score 0):

The error is `ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib' for architecture x86_64`.  Looks to me like that is a directory, not a file. You can run the cmake command on the line above and try adding `-L` in front.